# Running total joining two tables

Tags: sql, cumulative-sum

I have two tables

```
-----Dates-----          ------Sales------
Date    | Month          Date    | Quantity
---------------          ------------------
09/06/16| Jun            09/06/16| 2
09/07/16| Jul            15/07/16| 11
19/09/16| Sep            19/09/16| 12
21/09/16| Sep            09/07/16| 33
17/11/16| Nov            21/09/16| 45
```

I need to write an SQL query to calculate the running total of the sales in every month

Can I do it this way?

```
SELECT Month,
(SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM Sales WHERE Month<=Dates.Month)
FROM Dates, Sales
WHERE Dates.Date = Sales.Date
ORDER BY Month
```

I feel there's something wrong in my way of thinking, but I don't have a database to prove it

Comment: How can you run the query if you don't have a database? You need a `Group By Month` after the `Where`

Comment: For clarification... Given the entry `09/07/16| Jul` on the left table, do you want all orders in July '16 on or before that date?

Comment: whic db you are using

Comment: no db, it's a theoretical question, I only had a db structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN` and `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT Dates.Month, SUM(Quantity)
FROM Dates INNER JOIN Sales ON Dates.Date = Sales.Date
WHERE   Sales.Month <= Dates.Month
GROUP BY Dates.Month
ORDER BY Dates.Month
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use  month for join then sum and group by for total

```
  SELECT month(d.date),  SUM(s.Quantity)
  FROM Dates  d 
  LEFT JOIN  Sales S on month(d.date) = month(s.date)
  ORDER BY month(d.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,should work:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
Select DateName(mm,D.Date) as Month,MONTH(D.Date) as UsedByOrderByLater,Sum(S.Quantity) as SumForCurrentMonth
 FROM Dates as D
    Inner Join Sales as S
    ON S.Date = D.Date
Group by DateName(mm,D.Date),MONTH(D.Date)
)
Select CTE.Month,CTE.SumForCurrentMonth ,
SUM(CTE.SumForCurrentMonth) OVER(Order by CTE.UsedByOrderByLater
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as runningtotal
from CTE
```